# How to fix filter mismatch problem while using a Custom App Script Function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am an HR, who has a little background in IT field, working in a small company. In order to bring the automation in the calculation of Attendance and Over-Time, I made a custom function in App-Script and invoked the function using a filter. It gives a perfect calculation, but on times, it gives "Filter Mismatch" error, which is rectified only after cutting and pasting the formula at the same location.

I made a custom function in App-Script and invoked the function using a filter.

```
function calculateOT(otAllowedNotSun, otAllowedSun, data, attendance, day) 
{
    var result;
    if(day=="Sun"){
      result = calculateOTSunday(otAllowedSun, attendance, data);
    }
    else {
      result = calculateOTExceptSunday(otAllowedNotSun, attendance, data);
    }
    return result;
}
```

// It is only a part function

I expected to refresh the results automatically. But instead it gives me "Filter Mismatch" Result.

Please Use this link to know more - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FNyqZ.jpg

Comment: To debug this function, on a new tab, run just the `calculateOT()` and see what the column of data looks like. And if that looks OK, then use the Filter function on that column.

Comment: It is not the problem of wrong output. The result is as what I am expecting. But sometimes it takes too long to do the computation, although the function is not so heavy. And during the computation, it show "Filter Mismatch" error. In order to solve it, I have to cut-and-paste the formula at the same location to get the instant result.

Comment: There is a [limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas) of 30 sec / execution for custom functions. A workaround could be to use an `onEdit()` script instead of a formula.

Answer (score 0):

As a user stated in the comments, apparently your problem is because the function is taking more than 30 seconds to run which is the limit for the custom functions [1]. You can workaround this by using a trigger (onEdit, onOpen, etc) [2], or you could implement a menu which you can click inside the Sheets UI to run the function that will set the formula to the cell. Like this:

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
  .createMenu('test')
  .addItem('Run...', 'calculateOT')
  .addToUi();  
}

function calculateOT(otAllowedNotSun, otAllowedSun, data, attendance, day) {
  var result;
  if(day=="Sun") {
    result = calculateOTSunday(otAllowedSun, attendance, data);
  }
  else {
    result = calculateOTExceptSunday(otAllowedNotSun, attendance, data);
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  var formulaCell = sheet.getRange("P5");

  formulaCell.setFormula('=FILTER(' + result + ', $B5:$B8<>"")');
}
```

I used the onOpen trigger [3] to insert the menu in the Sheets UI. With the setFormula() function [4] i set the formula with the result variable in the cell.

[1] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas

[2] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/

[3] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus

[4] https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula